# Where do I set the returnUrl path in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Good morning. I have been looking for several places to solve this problem. When you click the login button, the path to ~ / Home is displayed. Where is the place to set this path? Can I specify the path?

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // 계정이 잠기는 로그인 실패로 간주되지 않습니다.
        // 암호 오류 시 계정 잠금을 트리거하도록 설정하려면 shouldLockout: true로 변경하십시오.
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.ID, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "잘못된 로그인 시도입니다.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your view for login

Comment: Not clear what your asking. When a user navigates to a page on your that required authentication they are automatically redirected to the `Login` and the framework sets the value of `returnUrl` to the previous page so that the user is redirect back to that page if the login is successful.

Comment: If the login succeeds, do you mean to return to the previous page?

Comment: Yes, that is the default behavior. What are you wanting to do?

Comment: Well, `returnUrl` is a default parameter to redirect into previous page when authentication required to access that page (assume you're using default provider). You can use `Request.IsAuthenticated` check and `RedirectToAction("actionname", "controllername", new { returnUrl = "url here" })` but this way is not so viable as default behavior.

Comment: The login succeeded and the path is returned to ~/Home. I want to change this path to ~/Index, but where should I change it? I want to change the route. Also, ~/Home is not my previous page.

Answer (score 0):

provide a proper controller and Action Name in RedirectToAction :

```
switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "잘못된 로그인 시도입니다.");
                return View(model);
        }
```

and if you want to pass any external thing like paramerter or id then

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName",new { parameterToShowinURL = YourParameterOrVariableContainingValue });
```